# How to show Alert after popToRootViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, navigation, viewcontroller, uialertcontroller

How can i show an alert in my rootviewcontroller after popping to it from another Viewcontroller higher up the hierachy?

The setup is like this:

TabbarController <- NavigationController <- ViewController <- ViewController <- Viewcontroller

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let root =  self.navigationController!.viewControllers[0]
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.8) {
  let alert = ///
  root.present(alert....
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works now. Maybe i didnt put enough delay, 0.8 seems perfect to me.